# Android: Scanner read next line from csv and write to string

Tags: java, android, csv, readfile

i am confused.
this is my csv file

```
monday;;test;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;test;;
tuesday;;test2;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;test2;;
```

i need to read all lines that exists in this file and write them in separate String. Unfortunately it reads only the last line.

Here is my code:

```
String filename = String.valueOf(RecyclerViewSampleActivity.itemTexte.get(weekID));
    Scanner read = null;
    try {
        read = new Scanner(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/Test/Test2" + File.separator + filename));

    read.useDelimiter(";;");
    String start, text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6 ,text7;

    while (read.hasNext())
    {
        start = read.next();
        text1 = read.next();
        text2 = read.next();
        text3 = read.next();
        text4 = read.next();
        text5 = read.next();
        text6 = read.next();
        text7 = read.next();
        mondayText1.setText(text1.toString());
        mondayText2.setText(text2.toString());
        mondayText3.setText(text3.toString());
        mondayText4.setText(text4.toString());
        mondayText5.setText(text5.toString());
        mondayText6.setText(text6.toString());
        mondayText7.setText(text7.toString());
        if (!read.hasNext())
        {
            if (read.hasNextLine())
            {
                read.nextLine();

                tuesdayText1.setText(text1.toString());
                tuesdayText2.setText(text2.toString());
                tuesdayText3.setText(text3.toString());
                tuesdayText4.setText(text4.toString());
                tuesdayText5.setText(text5.toString());
                tuesdayText6.setText(text6.toString());
                tuesdayText7.setText(text7.toString());

            }
        }
    }
    read.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When i read the csv i get only the second line, and this one is filled in monday strings. My target is, read all possible lines, and write them in different strings(monday/tuesday...). I will add later other weekdays too. I would appreciate any help and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first `if` in the `while` loop to `if (read.hasNext())`

Currently, the condition in `if` is evaluating to false and so it doesn't go inside the loop. The while loop repeats for the second line and you get last line data in the monday strings.

Comment: Thanks! It made the trick. Just needed additionally change the tuesdayText and mondayText around to have the right place in my Text fields.